# Transpiled JavaScript code fails when I use decorator with gas-webpack-plugin

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, webpack, babel-loader, clasp

**EDIT1:I made a minimum reproduction repository [here](https://github.com/soracore/gas-ts-decorator-problem)**
code & reproduction steps are available at the repository.
**EDIT2: Same error occurs when I embeded the transpiled code on html file.**

**EDIT3: I tracked down the main cause of this problem.**
When I use gas-webpack-plugin, output file pukes this error. Simply removing the plugin solves the problem, but then I cannot access my main function on GAS.
I created a [github issue on the official gas-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/fossamagna/gas-webpack-plugin/issues/685) . Hope there's a workaround for this.

**---Original question from here---**

I'm using Clasp + Typescript + Webpack + Babel to locally develop GAS with npm libraries.
Until I used decorator in my project, it was working fine. However, using decorator(more precisely, class-validator) results in following error on GAS...

```
TypeError: (0 , _metadata_MetadataStorage__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.getMetadataStorage)(...).addConstraintMetadata is not a function(line 482, file "index")
```

Does anyone know how to avoid above error?

here's the sample code and configs.

```
// index.ts

import { IsOptional, IsString } from 'class-validator';

declare const global: {
  [x: string]: any;
};

class Foo {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  foo: string;
}

// ENTRYPOINT
global.main = function (e: any) {
  console.log('Hello World!');
  const hoge = new Foo();
};
```

```
// .babelrc (with babel-loader v8.2.3)
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-typescript"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "decoratorsBeforeExport": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ]
}
```

```
// tsconfig.json (with TypeScript v4.1.3)
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es5"], // changing this to es6 or esnext doesn't fix the problem
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a set of reproduction steps for this? When are you getting this error, when uploading the code, or when trying to execute what function?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated my question (added reproduction github repository) https://github.com/soracore/gas-ts-decorator-problem

Comment: Try to set loose to false. and Please provide babel version

Comment: Thanks. I'm using babel-loader 8.2.3. (other lib's versions are also available on github repo's package.json). disabling loose option didn't solve the problem...

Comment: Hi, do you get the same behavior if you don't run it on GAS?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I get the same error when I embed it on html file :( So it looks like it's not GAS issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to the author of the gas-webpack-plugin.
https://github.com/fossamagna/gas-webpack-plugin/issues/685

When using decorators, gas-webpack-plugin exposes not only `main()` but also `classValidatorMetadataStorage()` to the top level.
By simply removing this from the transpiled file, I was able to run the code with decorators.

But we now don't have to do this manually now. The author already took care of the situation.
As of gas-webpack-plugin@2.2.0, it has include option to avoid unnecessary function exposure.

Usase:

```
new GasPlugin({
  // Only functions written here is moved to the top level.
  include: ["src/**/*.ts"]
})
```